# Mathematical Statistics book suggestion

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

I recently took a very demanding course on statistics. One of my main difficulties (I am an economist) was to "visualize" joint and conditional distributions, and difficulties in calculating integrals. Regarding the integrals, I had a hard time finding the integration interval. It was painful! In the next semester I will attend this discipline again.

Could you suggest some statistical or mathematical book or even Statistics/Mathematical book, that gives a greater focus on this issue of visualization of distributions and integral, and intervals of integration?

Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability and Statistics by DeGroot and Schervish is an excellent book. I would start there. I felt that it provided wonderful examples that went beyond just proofs and formulas, if that is mean when you said you were having difficulty "visualizing" joint and conditional distributions. I also felt that the text was very student friendly, I would even recommend it for self study if it were not a required textbook for a class.

Comment: If you have personal experience with this book, perhaps you can address in some detail the requirement, "gives a greater focus on this issue of visualization of distributions and integral, and intervals of integration."  Be wary of providing Answers that are significantly shorter than the Question to which they respond.

Answer (score 2):

I have read the DeGroot and Schervish book, and I can attest that it has great examples.

However another possible book to look at is Mathematical Statistics by Jun Shao. It's a Springer text, and is probably for an advanced undergrad or a grad student, but it covers a lot of the topics you are interested in. That being said Springer textbooks are of excellent quality. Hope this helps.